# Error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: android, jvm

I want to extract the source code from the apk file.
Fot that purpose i referred a link given on net.But when i am running the dex2jar classes.dex on command prompt i am getting
"Error ocurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the JVM "
Please guide me how to overcome this error.

Answer (score 3):

edit file **dex2jar.bat** in your folder. Change this:

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp %CLASSPATH% "com.googlecode.dex2jar.v3.Main" %*
```

the memory setting should be smaller.

Answer (score -2):

For Source code you need 2 tools

```
 i) dex2jar 
ii) jd-gui
```

for using this tools you need a .apk file then

```
 step 1 : Right click on that .apk file and convert it into .zip 
 step 2: unZip that file then take classes.dex from this unzip folder 
 step 3: Go to cmd then go to the path of dex2jar folder like D:\dex2jar tools\dex2jar-0.0.9.8\dex2jar-0.0.9.8 
 step 4: write dex2jar classes.dex
 step 5: press Enter 
 step 6: then see in path   D:\dex2jar tools\dex2jar-0.0.9.8\dex2jar-0.0.9.8  you can see a .zip file of classes then unzip and
 step 7 : import that files in jd-gui software
```

Comment: OP is asking about the error "Error ocurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap Could not create the JVM", and not the de-compilation steps